# color marginnote text in article

Tags: color, margins, text

I managed to rescue some code, and I am able to add side notes using the marginnote package.

Now I want to change the color of the margin text, but no matter how much I look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/add-colour-to-margin-notes), I do not seem to get it to work on my code... (I understand this question might be considered a duplicate).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%Page geometry
\RequirePackage[left=6cm,top=2cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}

\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=blue]{Arial}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Side Box %
%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\RequirePackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar% Use the left side, not the default right side

\setlength{\marginparsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}

\RequirePackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{sidebox}[1][0pt]{%
    \marginnote{
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}
        \begin{flushright}
            \BODY
        \end{flushright}
    }[#1]
}



\begin{document}


\begin{sidebox}
    HELLO THERE, I AM SOME TEXT THAT WANTS TO BE RED
\end{sidebox}


\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `\addfontfeature`. Note I replaced  all your `\RequirePackage` (used for classes and packages) with `\usepackage`:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%Page geometry
\usepackage[left=6cm,top=2cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=blue]{Arial}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Side Box %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar% Use the left side, not the default right side

\setlength{\marginparsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4cm}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{sidebox}[1][0pt]{%
    \marginnote{\addfontfeature{Color = red}
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}
        \begin{flushright}
\BODY
        \end{flushright}
    }[#1]
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidebox}
    HELLO THERE, I AM SOME TEXT THAT WANTS TO BE RED
\end{sidebox}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: damn so simple, and I couldn't figure it out... that other question confused me